# How do I DI Repositories/Services in Android Hilt when they are chosen using stateful data?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I am running into an organizational issue with DI and I don't quite know the best way to solve it.

I've created a view that displays a list of either cats or dogs. This is determined by data sent to the ViewModel on initial creation, and doesn't change for the view's lifecycle.

(Ignore any syntax problems, this is just to make the example easier to explain)

```
Abstract class ListData(){...}
class CatListData() : ListData(){}
class DogListData() : ListData(){}

Enum class Sourcetype{
  Dog, Cat, OtherSourcesIAddLater
}

class CatRepository @Inject constructor(val source :CatDataSource){
  fun getCatData(): Flow<CatListdata>{...}
}

class DogRepository @Inject constructor(val source : DogDataSource){
  fun getDogData(): Flow<DogListData>{...}
}

@HiltViewModel
class ListDataViewModel @Inject constructor(???) : ViewModel()
  fun selectDataSource(type: Sourcetype){???}
  fun getListData(): ListData{...}
}
```

Because this is stateful data I cannot use Dependency Injection to determine my Repository at compile time. As far as I know @AssistedInject can't help with that.

My first thought was to create & inject a RepositoryFactory that would determine which one to use with the stateful data. However, the repository classes then can't be created through DI since the factory is creating then which becomes its own problem due to having to inject other sources the Repositories use.

I also can't make a Factory for the sources because they data they collect is too different.

Is there a way to have the factory class create objects through DI or should I be using another pattern all together?

Comment: have you tried `interface CatRepository { fun getCatData() }` then `class CatRepo @Inject constructor(val source : DogDataSource):CatRepository` so you would just do a `@HiltViewModel class ListDataViewModel @Inject constructor(val repoA:CatRepository) : ViewModel()`? Selecting datasource seems a completely different subject.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by using multibinding for the different Repositories, for example:

```
@IntoMap
@Provides
@StringKey("cat")
fun getCatRepository(source : CatDataSource) : IRepository{...}

@IntoMap
@Provides
@StringKey("dog")
fun getDogRepository(source : DogDataSource) : IRepository{...}

class RepositoryFactory @Inject constructor(val map : Map<String, IRepository>){
    getRepositoryType(type : Sourcetype) : IRepository {
      val key = when(type){
           SourceType.Cat -> "cat"
           SourceType.Dog -> "dog"
       }
      return map[key]!!
  }
}
```

I could probably condense it by having the enum values equal to the mapped string. But overall this lets me select a repository implementation at runtime while still getting to use DI for construction.  It also scales up well if I need more than 2 repository types.